# Why is shallow copy needed for my values dictionary to correctly update?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration, artificial-intelligence

I am working on an `Agent` class in Python 2.7.11 that uses a [Markov Decision Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) (MDP) to search for an optimal policy **π** in a `GridWorld`. I am implementing a basic value iteration for 100 iterations of all `GridWorld` states using the following Bellman Equation:

[image]

- ***T(s,a,s')*** is the probability function of successfully transitioning to successor state **s'** from current state **s** by taking action **a**.
- ***R(s,a,s')*** is the reward for transitioning from **s** to **s'**.
- ***γ*** (gamma) is the discount factor where **0 ≤ γ ≤ 1**.
- ***V<sub>k</sub>(s')*** is a recursive call to repeat the calculation once **s'** has been reached.
- ***V<sub>k+1</sub>(s)*** is representative of how after enough **k** iterations have occured, the **V<sub>k</sub>** iteration value will converge and become equivalent to **V<sub>k+1</sub>**

This equation is derived from taking the maximum of a **Q** value function, which is what I am using within my program:

[image]

When constructing my `Agent`, it is passed an MDP, which is an abstract class containing the following methods:

```
# Returns all states in the GridWorld
def getStates()

# Returns all legal actions the agent can take given the current state
def getPossibleActions(state)

# Returns all possible successor states to transition to from the current state 
# given an action, and the probability of reaching each with that action
def getTransitionStatesAndProbs(state, action)

# Returns the reward of going from the current state to the successor state
def getReward(state, action, nextState)
```

My `Agent` is also passed a discount factor, and a number of iterations. I am also making use of a `dictionary` to keep track of my values. Here is my code:

```
class IterationAgent:

    def __init__(self, mdp, discount = 0.9, iterations = 100):
        self.mdp = mdp
        self.discount = discount
        self.iterations = iterations
        self.values = util.Counter() # A Counter is a dictionary with default 0

        for transition in range(0, self.iterations, 1):
            states = self.mdp.getStates()
            valuesCopy = self.values.copy()
            for state in states:
                legalMoves = self.mdp.getPossibleActions(state)
                convergedValue = 0
                for move in legalMoves:
                    value = self.computeQValueFromValues(state, move)
                    if convergedValue <= value or convergedValue == 0:
                        convergedValue = value

                valuesCopy.update({state: convergedValue})

            self.values = valuesCopy

    def computeQValueFromValues(self, state, action):
        successors = self.mdp.getTransitionStatesAndProbs(state, action)
        reward = self.mdp.getReward(state, action, successors)
        qValue = 0
        for successor, probability in successors:
            # The Q value equation: Q*(a,s) = T(s,a,s')[R(s,a,s') + gamma(V*(s'))]
            qValue += probability * (reward + (self.discount * self.values[successor]))
        return qValue
```

This implementation is correct, though I am unsure why I need `valuesCopy` to accomplish a successful update to my `self.values` dictionary. I have tried the following to omit the copying, but it **does not work** since it returns slightly incorrect values:

```
for i in range(0, self.iterations, 1):
    states = self.mdp.getStates()
    for state in states:
        legalMoves = self.mdp.getPossibleActions(state)
        convergedValue = 0
        for move in legalMoves:
            value = self.computeQValueFromValues(state, move)
            if convergedValue <= value or convergedValue == 0:
                convergedValue = value

        self.values.update({state: convergedValue})
```

My question is why is including a copy of my `self.values` dictionary necessary to update my values correctly when `valuesCopy = self.values.copy()` makes a copy of the dictionary anyways every iteration? Shouldn't updating the values in the original result in the same update?

Comment: This has almost as much math as it does code. I approve.

Comment: Yes, Artificial Intelligence is incredibly mathematics heavy, especially in the Calculuses.

Comment: What is `util.Counter()`?

Comment: `Counter` is a class that extends `dictionary` and defaults all key values to 0. There doesn't appear to be any `update()` method in its definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an algorithmic difference in having or not having the copy:

```
# You update your copy here, so the original will be used unchanged, which is not the 
# case if you don't have the copy
valuesCopy.update({state: convergedValue})

# If you have the copy, you'll be using the old value stored in self.value here, 
# not the updated one
qValue += probability * (reward + (self.discount * self.values[successor]))
```

Comment: Is there any way around this? I know I don't necessarily need to, but I find copying out-of-place to be wasteful in space and processing

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but it looks like you replace all your states in the copy by new ones. So why make a copy in the first place. Wouldn't creating an empty dict for each iteration instead of the copy work just as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But it does not.

Comment: To be clear I do not say you should only use the original dictionary. I suggest you create a new one for the new values, leaving the previous one to compute from. From your answer I gather that you tried that and that it doesn't work. I have to admit I don't know why. Sorry.